# how to set up multiples databases in Virtuoso triplestore?

Tags: semantic-web, virtuoso, linked-data

Can I set up multiples triplestores in Virtuoso in the same way I create multiples databases in, for example, a conventional mysql DBMS? Each database would be independent with (possibly) its own sparql endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can,

at least as far as i understood your question.
You can add additional datastes to the virtuoso triple store under a new graph, which you would use in the FROM statament of your queries to point out the named graph you want your results to stem from:

```
create graph <http://myNewAndShinyGraph.org/some/path>;
```

Now you can add/upload you dataset into the triplestore under the new context you created. (As usual via SPARQL INSERT, TTLP or ld_dir...)

You can also expose this graph with a different SPARQL endpoint.
Follow the steps described by Hugh Williams here: [Defining endpoints in Virtuoso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605285/defining-endpoints-in-virtuoso)

Also of interest: [How to create a SPARQL endpoint using Virtuoso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953552/how-to-create-a-sparql-endpoint-using-virtuoso)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely broad and difficult to answer both concisely and usefully.  The short answer is "Yes," but that seems less than useful.

[Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) (produced by my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/)) *is* a "conventional" SQL-style DBMS, akin to MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc., though being a hybrid engine, it is also a NoSQL, graph/RDF, XML, object, and various other style DBMS.  In the graph/RDF realm, it is actually a Quad Store, which allows for use as either a simple triplestore, or a collection of Named Graph whether each might be considered a separate triplestore...

One Virtuoso DB file may contain multiple SQL-style CATALOGS, as well as multiple Named Graphs and other divisions of RDF/graph data, for which you can set up distinct SPARQL endpoints -- or you can set up distinct DB files (and Virtuoso instances), each with one database/data set.  There may be other options appropriate to your needs ...

Virtuoso-specific questions are often better raised in Virtuoso-specific areas, such as the public [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the public [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), a confidential [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp), etc.